# how to populate information from sales force dynamically to application

Tags: ios5, salesforce, xcode4.5

We need to create questions and related options in sales force and need to populate them in my application as well (question and multiple options together). I searched a lot in google,but no related information regarding this.

Any help could be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: SO yo want to store some data in salesforce and then this data needs to be populated in another application database? If yes, then do you want the data to flow from salesforce to your applicaiton when the data is created or will you be pulling the data to your application from salesforce? You should look at REST API or SOAP API provided by salesforce. Incase you're processing lot of data then you should take look at BULK API..

Answer (score 0):

To consume data from Salesforce from your iOS application you should start taking a look at the [Salesforce Mobile SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS).

A good place to read and get started with iOS and SF integration is the [Salesforce mobile guides](http://www2.developerforce.com/mobile/getting-started/ios)

You may find information on the same site about Salesforce integration with other mobile platforms as well.